# How to upload an image to a Ruby server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, mime-types

I'm creating a simple HTML page that has an image upload. That image then gets sent to a Rails back-end (assume `http://www.mycompany.com/myapp/post/`).

I need to:

- Send the MIME-type binary of the image as a parameter called "chart"
- Send some params through the POST

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails or not, just:

```
<form action="URL_GOES_HERE" method="POST"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" name="file"><br/>
<!--- USE HIDDEN FOR YOUR EXTRA PARAMS -->
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This is great. How do I send the actual file itself through the POST? I have a parameter called "chart" that will be the image binary.

Comment: The above code will send using the post, (the actual file). just change name="file" to name="chart". That input 'is' the file.

Answer (score 1):

Use the excellent Paperclip plugin to do all of the work for you: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is CarrierWave https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave